# Comparison between two objects in Python + IDLE using the id () function with different result

Tags: python, python-3.x

Searching, I noticed that the `id()` function returns an integer and that guarantees be unique and constant for the object.

When comparing two different objects getting results, which may have allowed these different results ??

I saw an example in an ebook that comparison `id(Car()) == id (Car())` returns `False` but when running the same code returned `True`

class Car.py

```
class Car:
    pass
```

Code in Idle

```
>>> from Car import Car
>>> ferrari = Car()
>>> lamborghini = Car()
>>> id(lamborghini) == id(ferrari)
False
>>> id(Car()) == id(Car())
True
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Comment: Whether or not `id(object()) == id(object())` or not is not really a Python question.  It depends on the implementation and whether it a) immediately destroys unneeded objects and b) reuses the last space freed for the next object.  At least some versions of CPython do this for at least some object classes.  The main use of id() is to test details of an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering why `id(ferrari) == id(lamborghini)` is false but `id(Car()) == id(Car())` is true. This is because when you say `ferrari = Car()`, Python generates a new object **based** on Car structure. So `ferrari` is a **new object** with unique id only to `ferrari`.

In `id(Car()) == id(Car())`  the true evaluation comes from the fact that `Car` objects don't live outside of the `id()` call.

I hope this helps!

Comment: You are ignoring the second part of the question, which is why does `id(Car()) == id(Car())` evaluate to `True`?

Comment: `id(Car()) == id(Car())` both refer to the same Car class. If I had a piece of paper with instructions, it will always be the same piece to paper each time I point to it. But if I used those paper instructions to make 2 cars. They would be different objects, even though they were made using the same piece of paper with instructions.

Comment: Wrong.  `Car()` is an object created from the `Car` class.  For the correct explanation see my answer.

Comment: Just to add on a little more.  In this statement `id(Car()) == id(Car())` two `Car` objects are created.  They do not need to be assigned to any names to exist as objects. Your explanation would be correct if the code had been `id(Car) == id(Car)` but it was `id(Car()) == id(Car())`.

Comment: Shoot, you're right, I added that comment too quickly. Car() instantiates a Car object and so the true evaluation comes from the fact that they don't live outside of the `id()` call.

Comment: "Car() instantiates a Car object and so the true evaluation comes from the fact that they don't live outside of the id() call."  A very succinct summary.  Add that info to your answer and I'll change my downvote to an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` of any object is supposed to be unique so it seems that `id(Car()) == id(Car())` should be `False`, but it is evaluating to `True`.  However, the `id` of an object is only guaranteed to be unique *during that object's lifetime*.  Since these `Car` objects are transitory they only last long enough to be passed to `id()` and then they are garbage collected.  Python is evaluating one side of the `==`, garbage collecting, and then evaluating the other side.  In the process the `id` gets reused for each `Car()` object.

For a longer explanation see [abarnert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753450/1322401) to [Why is the id of a Python class not unique when called quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753364/why-is-the-id-of-a-python-class-not-unique-when-called-quickly)

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation:

id(object): Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.

You are creating two distinct instances of the class `Car`, namely `ferrari` and `lamborghini`, therefore their identifiers are different.

Comment: You are ignoring the second part of the question, which is why does `id(Car()) == id(Car())` evaluate to `True`?