# Why do these print()s print the same id?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Problem**

```
print(id([1,2,3,[1,3]]))
hello = [1,2,3]
print(id(hello))
```

output:
4344840704
4344840704

I don't really understand why those two list have the same id?
Thanks

Comment: i think this is the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38189759/6593287

Comment: @СергейКрылов no, that's about the id of small integers; this is about the ids of two different lists.

Comment: Well,
The similiar question my post has been associated to doesn't really answer to my question. 
I found the answer in another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372886/different-lists-in-python-in-size-and-content-still-share-the-id-does-memory-ma

I understand why the same id is printed: The lists don't exist at the same time.
```
hola = id([1,2,3,[1,3]])
hello = [1,2,3]
print(id(hola))
print(id(hello))
```
By doing this, I have now 2 differents ids